# Make a string of Christmas lights slowly brighten and dim

Tags: mosfet, timer, triac

OK, here's my Christmas light project and I didn't see this one asked yet on StackExchange.

What I am trying to achieve: have a single string of incandescent Christmas lights slowly dim and brighten repetitively.  And by slowly I mean a period of between 1s and 5s, adjustable by the user.  So kind of like having them on a dimmer that is modulated from 0% to 100% to 0% over and over.  I want them to dim and brighten - not flash.

Generating what essentially is a **triangle** (edit: was sawtooth) driver signal in the 1s to 5s period is simple enough using op amps (or perhaps a couple 555's), but where I am struggling is how to use that low level driver signal to control 115VAC.  The two methods I am considering are:

1. Use a Triac.  That will handle the voltage easily, but I'd need an intermediate circuit to convert the instantaneous magnitude of the triangle to an appropriately timed 60Hz pulse to trigger the Triac.  And that pulse would have to be phase synchronized to the mains AC.  Not an easy task I think.
2. Use an isolation transformer and rectifiers and drive the bulb string with DC.  Then use an N-channel MOSFET circuit similar to a dynamic load circuit to add effectively a variable resistor to the light string.  I'd need the triangle voltage peak to peaks set to go from cut-off voltage to just at the ohmic/saturation point for the MOSFET, but that seems doable.

I'm leaning towards #2, **but here's the question: is there a simpler option #3 that I am overlooking?** (and no, it cannot be buying this gizmo already made, and no - it cannot involve using an Arduino or some other microcontroller - I want to keep it all analog hehehe).

If nothing simpler than #1 or #2, then because I prefer #2, my next step will be to do a first draft of a schematic for #2.

Lastly, I realize a triangle driver signal (e.g. a linearly increasing and decreasing signal) will not produce a linear change in brightness as perceived by the human eye - I do not care.  I just want the lamps to slowly change from off to on repetitively and not flash.

Comment: Far more difficult than you might think, because our eye perception of brightness is so very non-linear. You may find that a "ramp" up and down gives an unsatisfying  visible result.

Comment: There's no question included. Please ask a question that you'd like to have an answer.

Comment: It's very true about the non-linear nature of human eye photo response as @glen_geek says.   Your eyes HAVE to be non-linear or you wouldn't be able to see in the bright afternoon sun AND a moonless star-lit night.  Those differ in brightness about 1,000,000x   If you had linear eyes, your ancestors woulda been saber-tooth tiger food.  Your ears work the same way BTW, hence the 'decible' scale.   If you want this to LOOK "linear", you need to use a very non-linear control function.  Doing this analog won't work well.  Why can't you do it digital or just buy a pre-canned solution???

Comment: @justme are you not able to interpret the basic "is option 2 or 2 better or is option 3 that I haven't thunk of better" implied question? This isn't a pedantic language forum. "You didn't say the magic word" type responses are unhelpful.

Comment: @glen the driver section of this question is more important than the signal section. He can adjust that after they get help with the how to drive the bulbs.

Comment: +1 for asking a Christmas themed question!

Comment: https://circuitspedia.com/remote-control-ac-dimmer-arduino/

Comment: @KyleB _" If you want this to LOOK "linear", you need to use a very non-linear control function."_ but incandescent lamps also have a very nonlinear response https://www.quora.com/If-you-operate-an-incandescent-light-bulb-at-less-than-its-rated-voltage-what-will-happen

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  I edited my original post to add more details to my request.

Comment: @BruceAbbott  Well, I think we can agree that adding two non-linear functions does not sum to a linear one    ;)   $$$$  I only speak from experience... In my job (of 20 years) I've spent a ludicrous amount of time working with fading lights, synchronizing them to music ... Mostly LED's but incandescent also.   My experience has been that simple linear ramps look like cr*p - Very 'artificial' or 'robotic' -  Not the kind of smoothly flowing fades the OP likely has in his head.  But it definitely is an opinion and subject to personal interpretation.

Comment: ... and neither is the phase angle to rms voltage response of a TRIAC. My point is that until you plot the response of the entire system you won't know how linear it is.

Answer (score 1):

I did that. Design includes triac, optotriac, optotransistor, microcontroller and power supply+5V.  Optotransistor as null-comparator, MCU controls phase. Any sequence of brightness may be created, it is all in programm. And you may have control and test different algorithm, choose the best by appearance.

Comment: This answer could be much better if you flesh it out. Maybe add your schematic?

Comment: @passerby There is a lot of possibilities to design similar devices with different components. People used different sources and suppliers and may have some components in hands. The principles is very common.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a modulator to a standard phase-control TRIAC dimmer is a lot messier in practice than on paper.  Long ago I saw a schematic, and politely declined.  In fact, it probably would be easier to connect a gear motor to the shaft of a TRIAC dimmer potentiometer and control the motor.  Also, you get galvanic isolation between the power circuit and the control circuit.

Separate from that, I like the high-voltage DC option.  The waveform on an n-channel power MOSFET gate would be only about 3 V peak-to-peak, maybe from 2 V to 5 V, to drive the FET from threshold to fully enhanced.  And, as above, there will be a lot of visual compression at the bright end of the range, so driving the bulbs all the way from fully off to fully on probably won't look the way you want; visually, too much time at the ends, not enough time in the transitions.  This decreases even more the p-p height of the sawtooth waveform.

Bridge > very small capacitor for noise suppression, not a full-sized power supply filter cap > lights > MOSFET drain > MOSFET source > bridge.

Wall wart single-output power supply for the control circuit, with the supply return connected to the bridge - (return) output.

2-opamp triangle wave generator > gain and DC offset adjustments > MOSFET gate.

Note - the FET will get hot.  You will need a heatsink and fully-isolated device mounting.

AND - Offline AC power circuits are ***VERY DANGEROUS***.  No warranties expressed or implied.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is very old school but works. You need a zero-crossing detection circuit (to sync your pulses correctly) and an optoisolator to drive the TRIACs from DC. One way to get it to work is by comparing the voltage in a capacitor to the generated triangle wave. Charge this capacitor with a constant current, and use the zero crossing circuit to fully discharge it. This way, the output from the comparator will rise some time after the zero crossing event, and this time will depend on the triangle wave.

Option 2 sounds relatively easy, but uses bulky transformers and capacitors, and has very bad efficiency: your MOSFET will heat up like crazy.

---

Assuming this is a one-off learning/novelty project, my suggestion would be to do a few modifications to option 2: a far more efficient approach (but kinda digital-ish) would be to drive the MOSFET (maybe consider an IGBT?) with PWM generated from comparing the triangle wave with a very fast sawtooth wave. Also I'd use a switching power supply instead of transformers, but that sounds even more digital-ish.

Comment: You don't need to synchronize to zero crossing if you use a 59.5 Hz, or thereabouts signal to fire a 4 quadrant triac. Since poster doesn't care about non-linear appearance, one can just let the beat frequency take care of the dimming.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy that's such a cool idea I now feel I have to build one myself!

Comment: SMH, now that's a very interesting idea #3! I can see a 555 being adjusted from 59Hz to (near) 60Hz that drives the triac doing this.  I'm going to think about that idea some more.

Comment: @MisterHeadache I'm not sure an RC based timer like the 555 will be stable enough. It might be, but a small drift will cause a big change in flashing rate.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy this is a really cool idea, but with triacs you should get sawtooth waves (at 59.9Hz it lights up suddenly, at 60.1Hz it turns off suddenly). To get a low frequency sine wave through aliasing I think you need sampling (perhaps pulsing an inductor, flyback style)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but you could try using a standard potentiometer-controlled dimmer circuit, but replace the potentiometer with a resistor network that includes a light-dependent resistor (LDR). Illuminate the LDR with an LED driven by your triangle wave generator (and enclose it to exclude ambient light). Play with the resistance values until you get a satisfactory brightness variation.

You'd need to check that you don't exceed the voltage and power dissipation ratings of your LDR, which are often lower than those for typical potentiometers. Unfortunately the convenient [NSL-32 series devices](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/16352.pdf) which have the LED and LDR in one package have a maximum voltage rating of 60 V. The [NSL-4960 LDR](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/12656.pdf) will handle 320 V and 500 mW which should be more than enough, although it isn't cheap.